# Setting up audio stream from remote server

Tags: audio-streaming, internet-radio

I've got a very general question. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any tips online at all. There seem to be a lot of info on how to set up a radio stream from your home, but not from remote server.

I have a webpage with appropriate hosting set up. What ideally I'd like to do is to upload audio files over there and organize a radio stream. In addition, I'm planning to write some scripts to have streaming patterns, that is some customized scheduling...

Which tools do I need to do that? Firstly, to just have a .txt file with order of files to play and secondly, if possible the best way to customize the order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a lot of options documented to implement this, which can be found via google.  for example:

http://nunzioweb.com/streaming_audio-example.htm

http://www.selfseo.com/story-13698.php

http://www.iradeo.com/

Comment: The first link seem very promising, I can start from there. Thank you!

Comment: Just was waiting before the end of bounty if someone else got a more comprehensive answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you have sshd on your remote server, you can also stream your files manually via ssh, like this:

```
ssh user@192.168.2.101 "cat music.mp3" | mplayer -
```

I find this much easier to use in a script than 3rd party streaming software.

EDIT: If you have a text file with mp3 files to play you could do something like that:

```
ssh user@192.168.2.101 'cat <path to text playlist> | while read file; do cat $file; done' | mplayer -
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: http://www.icecast.org/

You can create playlists in the .m3u format and stream audio using icecast as an mp3 stream.

Here are a bunch of sample radio stations using icecast:
http://dir.xiph.org/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look on Flash-based RTMP audio-streaming - for example, last.fm and youtube use it. Though you won't be able to setup the streaming server for it on a usual virtual hosting, the same could be told about any large streaming service - any of them has scalable architecture with several servers, load balancing etc. You will need at least VPS to test this kind of streaming. Among RTMP-servers - there are several free ones, which you can use:
http://www.flashrealtime.com/list-of-available-rtmp-servers/
Another noteable example - is HTML5 streaming, one of the players:
http://www.projekktor.com/